# how to understand that SpringMVC resource-chain includes resolvers that I have not set

Tags: spring-mvc, static-resource

My dispatcher.xml sets resource chain like below:

```
<mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" cache-period="31536000">
        <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true">
            <mvc:resolvers>
                <!--<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.GzipResourceResolver"/>-->
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.CachingResourceResolver">
                    <constructor-arg ref="staticResourceCache"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.VersionResourceResolver">
                    <property name="strategyMap">
                        <map>
                            <entry key="/**">
                                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ContentVersionStrategy"/>
                            </entry>
                        </map>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver"/>
            </mvc:resolvers>
            <mvc:transformers>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.CachingResourceTransformer">
                    <constructor-arg ref="staticResourceCache"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.CssLinkResourceTransformer">
                    <!--<property name="allowedLocations" value="/static"> </property>-->
                </bean>
            </mvc:transformers>
        </mvc:resource-chain>
    </mvc:resources>
```

when I debug the codes ,I find that the resource chains has two PathResourceResolver,  why ?Thank you!
[ResourceHttpRequestHanndler state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RgqD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Spring is adding a default `PathResourceResolver` bean with the default id `pathResourceResolver`. You are explicitly declaring one but without an id, so you are ending up with 2.
The Spring Framework does this a lot - ie. it will create default beans for you unless you specify a bean with the same id.

You can test this theory by:
1) comment your `PathResourceResolver` out of your config? Do you end up with 1?
2) use your `PathResourceResolver` in your config, but give it the id `pathResourceResolver`? Do you end up with 1?

Comment: Also, see section 4.1 of this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources where it says "In fact, if no ResourceResolver is added to the ResourceChainRegistration, this is the default resolver."

Comment: Yes, you are right! It really adds a default PathResourceResolver and a CachingResourceResolver. But I do not know how to only use the resolvers that I have set and avoid to appear the default resolvers? It seems that spring adds default resolvers alwalys

Comment: I have just find there exist note in the spring-mvc-4.3.xsd:

Comment: To override the standard/default beans (including resolvers), simply define them as you have done, but make sure you give them the same id that spring would set on its default one

Answer (score 0):

I have just find there exist note in the spring-mvc-4.3.xsd:

```
<xsd:documentation source="org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceChainRegistration"><![CDATA[
Assists with the registration of resource resolvers and transformers.
Unless set to "false", the auto-registration adds default Resolvers (a PathResourceResolver) and Transformers
(CssLinkResourceTransformer, if a VersionResourceResolver has been manually registered).
The resource-cache attribute sets whether to cache the result of resource resolution/transformation;
setting this to "true" is recommended for production (and "false" for development).
A custom Cache can be configured if a CacheManager is provided as a bean reference
in the "cache-manager" attribute, and the cache name provided in the "cache-name" attribute.
        ]]></xsd:documentation>
```